# Refresh stdout in paramiko inside a running process

Tags: python, sockets, paramiko

I'm trying to mimic the following behavior in a Python script:
Me running the following command on a remote server using ssh:

> gdb attach `pidof prog`

Then I get the following "welcome" screen in gdb:

```
Excess command line arguments ignored. (22870)
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.0.1-debian
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
...
0xb7f53c1e in __read_nocancel () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:82
82      ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S: No such file or directory.
        in ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S
(gdb)
```

pressing "c" gives the following output:

```
(gdb) c
Continuing.
```

Then when I connect using netcat to the server using another port I get the following output in gdb:

```
[New process 22898]
```

The new process ID is all I need which is why I want to automate the process.

I have the following Python script:

```py
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s = paramiko.SSHClient()
s.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
s.connect(hostname, port, username, password)

stdin, stdout, stderr = s.exec_command("gdb attach `pidof prog`")

stdin.write("c\n") # Pressing C
stdin.flush()

input("Now connect using NC and press Enter")

while not stdout.channel.exit_status_ready():
    time.sleep(1)
    if stdout.channel.recv_ready():
        rl, wl, xl = select.select([stdout.channel], [], [], 0.0)
        if len(rl) > 0:
            data_out = stdout.channel.recv(1024)
            print data_out
```

The problem is, I am getting the same output but somehow I do not receive the "[New process *]", even when I connect using nc in the exact same way.
Moreover, Only when I close the nc connection I see the output, but then it is too late because the process has died.
It seems like the output's buffer needs to be refreshed at that point, which it doesn't seem to be doing

Comment: You might use s.exec_command("history | grep [SOME REGEX]`") to get Process id

Comment: That wouldn't work because history does not show output of previous programs, only the commands I typed

Comment: You are right... Defeated by a tooth pick...

Comment: What's the program that you connect to? Is it written by you? As a workaround: try sending `call sync(1)`?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems to use stdin after a command and capture the stdout and I fixed it my by using the option "get_pty=True".

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = s.exec_command("gdb attach `pidof prog`",get_pty=True)
```

The [Paramiko Documentation](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/channel.html#paramiko.channel.Channel.get_pty) says when using the get_pty=True option a dedicate pseudo-terminal is opened and the same documentation suggest that it should use the get_pty=True if you intend to use more commands/interact with it:

> **get_pty(*args, **kwds):**
>
> Request a pseudo-terminal from the server. This is usually used right
>   after creating a client channel, to ask the server to provide some
>   basic terminal semantics for a shell invoked with invoke_shell. **It
>   isn’t necessary (or desirable) to call this method if you’re going to
>   execute a single command with exec_command.**

Also, if you use the get_pty=True you will be able to perform more commands over the same shell. Consequently, it will be possible to perform `history | grep [SOME REGEX]` as suggested by [SunPaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9178078/sunpaz).